# Can I run a water line behind a stack vent?

Tags: plumbing, water, drain-waste-vent, spigot

I am attempting to move a hose bibb/spigot 10 feet horizontally (from in front of my driveway gate to behind it). The water line comes up from the foundation through a brick exterior wall. My plan was to cut into the drywall on the inside and run a PEX line from the existing copper piping to the new location.

However, between the current bibb location and the new location, there is a large stack vent that runs the entire length of the wall. There does seem to be enough room to run the PEX line behind the stack vent, between it and the exterior brick. Is this permissible/advisable, and if not, is routing the line up into the attic to bypass the vent my best bet?

Comment: I don't know code on this but it feels like trouble down the line-in the future. Water lines should not be exposed to the exterior weather and if running within hairs of the brick itself, its destined to meet cold air too. in exterior walls pipes still need insulation, would it have it in this application?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you, and what is your climate? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is that stack/ vent hot? I probably run the tubing under the Sheetrock more repair of the Sheetrock but then it would be ok just have to drill a hole in the studs.